# Display foreach loop variable value in bootstrap model in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my php code for display list of services

```
<?php foreach($services as $service) { ?>       
                        <a href="" id="fetch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn-block"><?php echo htmlentities($service->services_title); ?></a>
                    <?php }?>
```

Now i want to display detailed description in bootstrap model but it shows only the first loop value never shows  other values.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo htmlentities($service->services_title); ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<?php echo htmlentities($service->services_description); ?>   
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you are using `id="myModal"` to every modal. It should be unique for your every service.

Comment: @Root,  dude, In  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals , there is " Varying modal content based on trigger button " , which helps you what you want.

Comment: @shaz please give detailed solution:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So An overview code I provide, which you may need to edit to meet your exact needs...

```
// Append a unique data-target to every anchor    
// I assume the $service has id attribute

    <?php foreach($services as $service) { ?>       
         <a href="" id="fetch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-<?php echo $service->id;?>" class="btn-block"><?php echo htmlentities($service->services_title); ?></a>
    <?php }?>



// Now in your markup there should be multiple modals to be targeted by your anchor tags like 

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
</div>
```

**Note:** There can be other good approaches like keeping the same modal but calling it via ajax based on the anchor clicked. That way your markup will be less messy and data will be added on request

Comment: so can i place model in foreachloop?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to just make sure the `id` attribute is getting generated in correct manner. Like in respect to the anchor tags `data-target` attribute

Comment: @raheel khan its worked ,but is there any other better way to do this ?

Comment: @Root, please **accept answer** if working, so it helps others whether its working or not.

Comment: You better follow what bootstrap officially suggest you to do. Like the reference @SHAZ has given. Try that and see how far you can go. You can always post a new question after what you have tried. Best of luck :)